# Show Weather in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, weather, yahoo-weather-api, google-weather-api

Problem is simple: I`m looking for tutorials or open source examples, for display weather in my application. As I search I found some Flex (MXML) applications but I want something more clear and easy to go. Do you know any link or any simple code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following [this](http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-handy-as3-weather-app-with-the-yahoo-api--active-3651) tut.
It should guide your way from creating a new file to having a finished weather app.
Hope I helped :D

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, yes there is an example [here](http://mate.asfusion.com/page/examples) built with the Mate framework and it uses Yahoo weather API.

However I would suggest you that you learn instead how to use one of the 2 api you mentionned.
First, look if there is any as3 wrapper for these API. If not, it's just a matter of knowing how to use the URLRequest class.

Comment: I found this [link](http://weatherdoll.com/google-weather-api-flash.php) which is ok but I`m not sure about the icons for "Cloudy , Rainy ... " . Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Looking at this url : http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Paris, it seems you get enough information to know which icon you should display.